# How to declare multiple object with same class but using different properties in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, javabeans

I want declare multiple object using same class but different properties in Spring boot annotation

***application.properties***

```
test1.name=Ken
test2.name=Anthony
```

***the code example***

```
@Component
public class People {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @AutoWired
    public People man1;

    @AutoWired
    public People man2;

    System.out.println(man1.getName());
    System.out.println(man2.getName());
}
```

I try to add `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test1")` before declare man1

but it returned

```
The annotation @ConfigurationProperties is disallowed for this location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` is only allow to be placed on the `@Bean` method in the `@Configuration` class or at the class level. For the former case , it will map the properties from the `application.properties` to the bean instance , which means you have to :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test1")
    public People man1() {
        return new People();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test2")
    public People man2() {
        return new People();
    }
}
```

And since both `man1` and `man2` are the same type , you have to further use `@Qualifier` to tell Spring which instance you actually want to inject by specifying its bean name. The bean name can be configured by `@Bean("someBeanName")`. If `@Bean` is used without configuring the bean name, the  method name will be used as the bean name. (i.e. `man1` and `man2`)

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("man1")
public People man1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("man2")
public People man2;
```